# Change URL of page in browser without refreshing and HTML5 mode?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the URL in the address bar without triggering a page refresh in older browsers that doesn't support HTML5 History API?

Answer (score 0):

try out hash url concept.
also in javascript `onhashchange` event is present.